# Saving video file in UWP app using opencv VideoWriter causing 'Access denied'

Tags: c++, opencv, video, uwp, save

I am trying to save video file with VideoWriter in UWP app and code executes, but does not save file and gives the following output:

`onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\preventrundownbias.cpp(1310)\combase.dll!00007FFD4B64C2BC: (caller: 00007FFD4B64C0E9) LogHr(3) tid(5444) 80070005 Access is denied.`

This info in debug appears either after creating writer or calling writer.open(...).
The app has access to Videos Library directory. I have also checked adding dll files.

Comment: OpenCV uses fopen to access files which won't work in UWP, modify it to use [CreateFileFromApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-createfilefromappw) or [WinRT Storage APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage) instead.

Alternatively use IAT Patching feature of appx ( [uap7:ImportRedirectionTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap7-importredirectiontable) ) to redirect fopen/CreateFile to CreateFileFromApp